# What is "type" of a function with implict?

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a function with a signature like this:

```
 def tsadd(key: Any, time: Double, value: Any)(implicit format: Format): Option[Int]
```

And I want to create a list of some number of these functions for later evaluation.  How do I do it.  I tried creating a list like:

```
val pipelineCmds:List[(String,Double,Any)(Format) => Option[Int]] = Nil
```

and doing this:

```
pipelineCmds ++ r.tsadd(symbol, timestamp.getMillis.toDouble, value)
```

But the val didn't respond well the implicit param Format.  It expects to see a ] after the first set of parens.

The ultimate goal is to do something like

```
r.pipeline { p => 
  pipelineCmds.foreach(c => p.c)
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Because `(String,Double,Any)(Format) => Option[Int]` is not a valid type. I don't have any better help :)

Comment: Fair enough.  Generally, how would you put a function into a list?

Comment: What is your `p` variable supposed to be?

Comment: I can't seem to get the REPL to spit out the type with the `implicit` left in. When I tried to create a partially applied function (`tsadd _`) it would only give me back something when the implicit was materialized. Dunno if this helps at all. Might need to wrap to `(String,Double,Any,Format)`... hopefully someone can expand on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, functions with implicit parameters are annoying to work with.  The appropriate types are (your choice):

```
(String, Double, Any) => Format => Option[Int]    // As written
Format => (String, Double, Any) => Option[Int]    // Conceptually works more like this
String => Double => Any => Format => Option[Int]  // Completely curried
(String, Double, Any, Format) => Option[Int]      // Closest to how the JVM sees the method
```

but partial application of the function does not work well.  You can annoyingly annotate all your types to get the last version:

```
class Format {}   // So the example works
def tsadd(s: String, d: Double, a: Any)(implicit f: Format): Option[Int] = None
scala> tsadd(_: String, _: Double, _: Any)(_: Format)
res2: (String, Double, Any, Format) => Option[Int] = <function4>
```

but it's not much harder to write your own to be whatever shape you want:

```
def example(f: Format => (String, Double, Any) => Option[Int]) = f
scala> example(f => { implicit val fm=f; tsadd _ })
res3: (Format) => (String, Double, Any) => Option[Int] = <function1>
```

Of course, if you already know the implicit values when you're creating the list, you just need the type

```
(String, Double, Any) => Option[Int]
```

and you assign the functions like

```
tsadd _
```

Comment: Thanks.  All of the answers were helpful, but this one provided the most relevant info for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> val pipelineCmds:List[(String,Double,Any) => Format => Option[Int]] = Nil
pipelineCmds: List[(String, Double, Any) => (Format) => Option[Int]] = List()
```

But note that the "implicitness" is lost from function values and you must explicitly pass in a format.

Comment: Doesn't actually work--how do you load the function in there?

Answer (score 1):

As @pst mentioned in a comment, even if you declared a list of the appropriate type, I don't know how you'd assign anything to it.

One solution is to use:

```
def tsadd(key: Any, time: Double, value: Any, format: Format): Option[Int]
```

with an explicit `format` argument.  You can put such `tsadd` functions in a `List[...]` as usual.  Then to get the `implicit format` behavior you want you add that to the wrapper:

```
def invoke_tsadd(list_selector: Whatever, key: Any, time: Double, value: Any)(implicit format: Format): Option[Int] =
    selected_from_your_list(list_selector).tsadd(key, time, value, format)
```