# How to define a function that takes a function literal (with an implicit parameter) as an argument?

Tags: scala, parameters, implicit, function-literal

I want to be able to do something on these lines (won't compile):

```
def logScope(logger:Logger)(operation: (implicit l:Logger) => Unit) {/* code */ operation(logger) /* code */} 
def operationOne(implicit logger:Logger) {/**/}
def operationTwo(implicit logger:Logger) {/**/}
```

And then use it like so:

```
logScope(new ConsoleLogger){logger =>
    operationOne
    operationTwo
    }
```

But the nearest I've come to a working solution is this:

```
def logScope(logger:Logger)(operation: Logger => Unit) {/* code */ operation(logger) /* code */} 
def operationOne(implicit logger:Logger) {/**/}
def operationTwo(implicit logger:Logger) {/**/}

/* other code */

logScope(new ConsoleLogger){logger =>
    implicit val l = logger
    operationOne
    operationTwo
    }
```

I don't think the language currently allows such constructs, but still, any suggestions or workarounds to achieve similar results?

---

minor update: I've [created a gist](https://gist.github.com/1147757) with a slightly expanded version of the above code with a couple of attempts at simulating this kind of literal. As of now, CheatEx's version is the best one.

Comment: You might be interested in:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628484/what-is-type-of-a-function-with-implict

Comment: What's the motivation for this?  There appears to be zero value to the block of code you've written.  You explicitly define the implicit and then implicitly pass it to the code... why not just pass it explicitly in the first place?  I get that you're trying to do a particular thing here - granted - but I think what you're doing is confusing as all hell... why not just pass the object in?

Comment: @derek It's the [loan pattern](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/control-abstraction.html#9.4) at work. I agree the logScope code could be a little less dumber.

Comment: I get that it's the loan pattern - what I don't get is the hoops.  Using `operationOne(logger)` and `operationTwo(logger)` would seem to be appropriate here.

Comment: @derek It becomes a bit tiresome if you have to use the *scope* in fifty different places. logScope could be sessionScope, fileScope or any number of other *scopes* with methods using a particular resource (whether injected, or otherwise). One need not have to specify the argument every time.

Comment: Yeah, I think I get it, but I'm pretty sure you can't loan an implicit like that.  I've tried doing it a few different ways (probably the same ways you've tried) and it just doesn't scope.

Comment: @ben I looked at the example you linked to, and the accepted answer uses the same idea: assign the parameter to a local implicit variable in the function literal and then pass the block to the main function.

Comment: @derek I'm not too optimistic either. Anyway, [this](https://gist.github.com/1147757) is a slightly longer version of the above example. As of now, the choice is between the local assignment, *every time*, and passing a local function as the argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your second example try this:

```
logScope(Logger()) { implicit logger =>
  operationOne
}
```

It should work fine. The logic here is that 'implicit' is an attribute of particular value *inside* closure, not a part of the closure's interface.

Comment: It does! The shortest way yet.

Comment: Can't get any better than this, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to rely on the *dynamic scope pattern* instead of implicit parameters.
You can actually even combine both, like this:

```
import scala.util.DynamicVariable
object Logger {
  val defaultLogger = new ConsoleLogger( "DEFAULT: %s" )
  val currentLoggerVar = new DynamicVariable[Logger]( defaultLogger )
  implicit object DynamicScopeLogger extends Logger {
    def log( msg: Any* ) {
      currentLoggerVar.value.log( msg: _* )
    }
  }
}
trait Logger {
  def log( msg: Any* )
}
class ConsoleLogger( val pattern: String ) extends Logger {
  def log( msg: Any* ) { println( pattern.format( msg: _* ) ) }
}

def logScope[T](logger: Logger)( operation: => T ): T = {
  Logger.currentLoggerVar.withValue( logger )( operation )
}
def operationOne(implicit logger: Logger) { logger.log( "Inside operationOne" ) }
def operationTwo(implicit logger: Logger) { logger.log( "Inside operationTwo" ) }
def operationThree(implicit logger: Logger) { logger.log( "Inside operationThree" ) }
def operationFour(implicit logger: Logger) { logger.log( "Inside operationFour" ) }
```

A usage example:

```
operationOne
logScope(new ConsoleLogger("Customized Logger 1: %s")){
  operationTwo
  logScope(new ConsoleLogger("Customized Logger 2: %s")){
    operationThree
  }
  operationFour
}
```

Which results in:

```
DEFAULT: Inside operationOne
Customized Logger 1: Inside operationTwo
Customized Logger 2: Inside operationThree
Customized Logger 1: Inside operationFour
```

The current logger is passed implicitly "out of bounds" (we just use a global (and thread local) variable to store the current logger).
We could every well never mention `Logger` anywhere in the method signatures, and directly call `currentLoggerVar.value`.
Lifting the access to `currentLoggerVar.value` inside a default implicit Logger value  (the `DynamicScopeLogger` proxy) allows us to keep the logging methods untouched.
It also means that we can use dynamic scope by default, and override this behaviour when needed by simply defining a local Logger implicit that will then take precedence over `DynamicScopeLogger`.

The main disadvantages are:

- Depending on the speed requirements, may be too slow: accessing thread local storage has a cost, including (but not limited to) a lookup in map of the thread local variables.
- This relies on the fact that the lexical scoping matches the order of execution (which is generally the case, but not always).  As soon as it's not the case anymore, you will run into troubles.
  By example when calling map or flatMap on a `scala.concurrent.Future` (or simply `Future.apply`), the body of the map/flatMap may be executed in another thread, and thus the body will not necessarily use the expected logger:

  ```
  scala>import scala.concurrent.Future
  import scala.concurrent.Future
  scala>import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  scala>logScope(new ConsoleLogger("Customized Logger: %s")){
       |  Future{ operationOne }
       |}
  DEFAULT: Inside operationOne
  res5: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@1a38913
  ```

  In the above example, `operationOne` is called witihn the lexical scope of `logScope`, so we might expect to get the message `"Customized Logger 1: Inside operationOne"`,
  however we see that the default logger is used instead. This is because the execution of the `Future.apply`'s body is deferred and happens later on, on another thread (after we have reset the variable `Logger.currentLoggerVar` to its default value).