# making thread-local objects on scala

Tags: multithreading, scala, singleton

I'm writing a computational library in scala. Similar functionality I group into native scala singleton objects containing bunch of procedures and some statically allocated memory for O(1) temporal data.

This approach is suited for a single-thread use. But calling library functions from different threads simultaneously may overwrite temporal data and give incorrect answers to callers.

I may just copy this library and write thread-safe version by moving all statically allocated memory inside functions local space. But I prefer to avoid it by defining thread-local variables.

Is it possible in scala?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just use Java's `java.lang.ThreadLocal` class to store the variables.

```
val tl = new ThreadLocal[String]
tl.set("fish")
tl.get   // "fish"
```

Be aware that there is a nonzero performance penalty for doing this (~6 ns in my hands, as I recall).  If you're doing really lightweight stuff (e.g. incrementing an index), you might notice the difference in speed.

Comment: Also note that there is scala's `DynamicVariable` which is basically a wrapper around `InheritableThreadLocal`. It does not provide any option for non-inheritable thread locals though.

Comment: @ Régis Jean-Gilles Maybe it's not related strictly to OP's question, but: you mentioned `InheritableThreadLocal`, seems it does not combines well with `Executors` framework because of pooling. Is there a use case for such variables, besides stuff that is keeped in deprecated `new Thread().start()` ?

Comment: `DynamicVariable` is useful for implementing the *dynamic scope pattern*. See my other answer by example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13252952/1632462. However it must never be used in a multi-threaded context, where it just won't work.

Answer (score 13):

Since Java 8 release, there is a more declarative way to initialize `ThreadLocal`:

**Scala:**

```
val local = ThreadLocal.withInitial[String](() => "init value");
```

**Analogue in Java:**

```
ThreadLocal<String> local = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> "init value");
```

Until Java 8 release you had to do the following:

**Scala:**

```
val local = new ThreadLocal[String]{
  override def initialValue = "init value"
}
```

**Analogue in Java:**

```
ThreadLocal<String> local = new ThreadLocal<String>(){
    @Override
    protected String initialValue() {
        return "init value";
    }
};
```

**Note:**
Evaluation is lazy since you are passing `java.util.function.Supplier` lambda that is evaluated only once when `ThreadLocal#get` is called but value was not previously evaluated.